# Not allowed to call async on function converted with sync_to_async()

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, django-models

I am having problems with sync_to_async. I am getting the `You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.` error at the print statement, even though I used sync_to_async to convert the async function. If I do `print(type(masters))` instead, i get a QuerySet as type. Is there something I am missing? I couldn't find this specific case on the docs.

Here is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async


class Bot(commands.Bot):
    # ...
    async def on_message(self, msg):
        masters = await sync_to_async(self.subject.masters)()
        print(masters)
```

Here is the masters() function i'm trying to get results from:

```
from django.db import models


class Subject(models.Model):
    # ...
    def masters(self):
        from .subjectmaster import SubjectMaster
        return SubjectMaster.objects.filter(subject=self)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your QuerySet is not executed until it is printed and you print outside of the `sync_to_async` function. You need to evaluate the QuerySet in your method

```
class Subject(models.Model):

    def masters(self):
        from .subjectmaster import SubjectMaster
        # Force evaluation by converting to a list
        return list(SubjectMaster.objects.filter(subject=self))
```

An option, if you do not wish to return a list from the `masters` method is to run `sync_to_async` on the `list` function and pass it your queryset

```
masters = await sync_to_async(list)(self.subject.masters())
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! Although if I don't want to bake the list() logic into that function, is there a way to do this directly inside the sync_to_async() function instead somehow?

Comment: @Midnight You can pass `list` to `sync_to_async` instead, added an example to the answer

Comment: Thanks that's perfect, you're a lifesaver.